# C# WCF Service Application Base Address Issue

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis

I have a WCF Service Application which will be deployed through IIS.

The development URL for the service is http://localhost:42543/Loyalty.svc, however when it is published to the web server the url will be http://ServerName:1066/Loyalty.svc .

However, when I navigate to the URL i get the following error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

The web.config for the site is here:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsSecureBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="default" name="IISService.Loyalty">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsSecureBinding" name="secureService" contract="IISService.ILoyalty"/>      
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="IISService.SecurityValidation, IISService"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I am also using the basic transport secuirty model as outlined here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/implementing-username-password-security-in-wcf-service/.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just a wild guess: You haven't configured https for your the site hosting your service in IIS yet, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you do not have your respective servers configured for HTTPS.

IIS needs to have a port binding with HTTPS configured.  see
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Cassini does not support SSL and will not work.  IIS Express will need to have SSL turned on in Visual Studio.  See http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/723357/Enabling-SSL-with-IIS-Express-in-Visual-Studio